# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I got this error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token;` while running this line:
`while; do; clear; tree .git; sleep 1; done`

I got this line from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SJCYPsef54&t=2809s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The video shows

```
while :
do
    clear
    tree .git
    sleep 1
done
```

Running that as-is will work. If you want to put all the commands on a single line, you need to write it as

```
while :; do clear; tree .git; sleep 1; done
```

You can’t separate `do` from the following command with `;`, and you need the colon (`:`) following `while`, which defines the condition (`:` is the same as `true`, it always succeeds).

See [the looping constructs section of the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs) for details.

Comment: Similarly you don't use a semicolon after keywords of an `if` statement: `if condition_commands; then success_commands; else fail_commands; fi`